# I have a meta tag error in XHTML 1.0 strict document

Tags: xhtml, xhtml-1.0-strict

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd"> <!--Contains document type definition-->
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en"><!--means XHTML document is enclosed by the html tag-->
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" /> <!--this meta tag specifies the character set as utf-8 like in html-->

    <title>Private Medical Park Dentistry</title>
</head>
```

I had an error in w3 validator says:Error: Bad value Content-Type for attribute http-equiv on XHTML element meta.  From line 5, column 5; to line 5, column 74  head>↩

Answer (score 0):

*It wasn't until I was going to post my answer that I noticed that it was asked 10 months ago. I hope you already have solved the problem.*

The code that you published validates (if you add a body and a closing html-tag).

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Private Medical Park Dentistry</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Maybe you have an illegal invisible character in there, that was filtered out when you posted it here?